# what program would make this http request? have I been hacked?

Tags: security, http

I have a small digital ocean instance running a personal blog. I recently set up apache logging and noticed people are making requests trying to hack wordpress (I'm not running wordpress). I also noticed this request appearing a couple of times, and I'm not sure what would be making it:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2014:14:57:30 -0600] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126
```

Does anyone have any ideas? If there's a chance someone has put a root kit on this instance I'd just as soon throw it away and start over and secure the next one better.

Comment: Are you running cPanel on the machine? If so, see https://forums.cpanel.net/f5/apache-status-http-requests-options-http-1-0-a-105109.html

Comment: No I'm not. Apache + Django + PostgreSQL + GeoServer

Comment: there is absolutely no reason why if it's 127.0.0.1  it's local so no reason why you can't find out what program it is. netstat -aon see the PID. gotta be done when the request happens though

Comment: @OliverSalzburg okay, that makes me feel significantly better about it. If I was pwned, why would someone keep making that call? Doesn't seem like that makes sense.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a call Apache HTTPD does to monitor itself when [mod_status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html) is enabled to generate the [/server-status](https://www.apache.org/server-status) page. Or at least something of that kind. Personally, I wouldn't worry about it